# Quickest way to reverse a list? (Only adjacent elements may be swapped)

Tags: list, sorting, theory

This is a theoretical/mathematical question. Maybe someone will find a use for it though.

I was rearranging some layers in Inkscape, trying to reverse the entire stack, and I was wondering what would be the quickest (i.e. least moves) way to reverse a list given the constraint that you can only swap two adjacent items at a time.

The simplest way is something similar to a bubble sort:

a,b,c,d,e,f -> b,a,c,d,e,f -> b,c,a,d,e,f -> b,c,d,a,e,f -> ... -> f,e,d,c,b,a

But is there a quicker way?

Comment: [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: what's mathematical about this?

Comment: Why use swaps at all? Presumably this is a linked list ... why not just go from last to first

Comment: The list you're asking about - is it a linked list? or an arraylist, accessible by index?

Comment: This is a sounds variant of [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) puzzle, which is fairly interesting to look at to see how problems like this can be solved.

Comment: It was just something that came to me while tediously rearranging layers in an image. I thought there might be an application somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

No, I think what you have is the least number of swaps. You *have* to execute five in order to get `a` to the end, then four more to get `b` to the second-from-last position and so forth.

Any other swap made while moving `a` will not result in `a` getting any closer.

Hence the minimal swap count for `{a, b, c, d, e, f}` is `5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1`. This is about as efficient as a bubble sort so should probably be avoided for any decent sized data. However, even bubble sort is okay if the data sizes are small enough that no-one notices.

It appears to me that, if your domain is Inkscape, you're not going to actually *have* a particularly massive number of layers. For a more general domain, you would have to suck it and see :-)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to traverse the same list from the last element to the first. No swaps at all.